# Function notation in Walter Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I am soon going to start my first analysis course, which uses 'Baby Rudin' (a.k.a. Principles of mathematical analysis by W. Rudin).

I looked a bit through it and noticed that it does not use the notation for functions $f:X \rightarrow Y$ in the whole text (there is other 'minor' stuff on notation, like the subset/proper subset notation, but I know that notation is used by lots of mathematicians)

Of course I know that mathematical notation isn't the most relevant inside mathematics *at all*, but I don't want to get lost in future courses.

So I would like to ask, mainly to people who have experience with this text, is this a really important thing? Or would using this notation when writing notes be enough? I don't know if this is a big deal but I don't want to get lost in other courses I take in the future.

(I don't know if the tags are OK, please edit them if they are not)

Comment: You can safely assume (except in the later chapters) that $Y$ will always be $\mathbb{R}$ and that $X$ will always be some subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I believe Rudin typically uses '$E$' instead of $X$. In the later chapters, you deal with subsets of Euclidean space of arbitrary dimension. And only in the latest chapter, do you deal with abstract sets to discuss measure spaces. However, even though the first 3/4 of Rudin is near perfect, a decent instructor would likely not delve into these later chapters because there are better resources for those topics.

Comment: I don't think Rudin's peculiar way of specifying functions will cause any confusion.

Comment: Rudin does general metric spaces, in fact, not just subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a text in real analysis, Rudin seems to leave it unsaid that $\mathbb R$ is almost always the codomain of a function or family if it goes unsaid. (If it's an arbitrary metric space instead of $\mathbb R$, he seems to note it.) It's a bit lazy, but probably par for the course for calculus or real analysis texts.  Aside from that, he seems to say things like "$f$ maps $E$ into $Y$" quite a bit, which means exactly $f:E\to Y$.

That's what I noticed from a quick flip through the book.  If there are any more specific examples, note the section or page numbers and I'm sure we can explain them.  It can be a challenging book to get through, but the notation probably won't keep you up.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to ensure that this wouldn't cause any problems to me for any future analysis courses. I guess I will also use external resources due to the difficulty of the book and get used to 'more standard' notations in those sites. Thanks!